# Reports, Graphs and Charts with Export to PDF, Excel from JSON

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, json, datatable

I am looking for any utility class , API which will provide me facility to create Report ,Graph and Charts from JSON object.

Also need to Export Data to Excel, PDF Maintaining formatting. Kindly suggest

I have not yet started my implementation yet

Answer (score 0):

I have good expirience with [Jasper reports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/community-wiki). Its free and mature library to handle what you need. They also have [reports designer](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/ireport-designer) to create tempaltes where you can definitely use [json as a datasource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jsondatasource/).